# How do I disable automatic closing of <> without disabling it for other brackets () {}?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I am getting annoyed by the autocompletion of the `<>` brackets  in VSCode for Rust. While it might be useful when specifying generic types, it really bothers me when it autocompletes ">" for my smaller than operators.

I know I can disable autoclosing brackets completely, but is there a way to specify which of them should be considered brackets? I have installed the Rust extension, and without it, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular brackets were added to `autoClosingPairs` in [this pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/vscode-rust/pull/720#issuecomment-615205869) on the premise that Rust developers write generics more than comparison logic. This choice was re-discussed [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/vscode-rust/issues/719) tp no avail. It seems that there is no way to differentiate between generics and comparisons with vscode's current configuration options. However, there are two ways to remove this behaviour manually. One is to disable auto closing for *all* brackets by adding this line to your `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never"
```

The other solution is to disable autoclosing for only angular brackets by removing the rust extension's configuration locally:

```json
// .vscode/extensions/rust-lang.rust-x.x.x/language-configuration.json

"autoClosingPairs": [
  { "open": "<", "close": ">" },
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ remove this line
]
```