# How to prevent rust.vim plugin from automatically inserting closing angular bracket?

Tags: vim, rust, vim-plugin, neovim

This question is the neovim version of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64942734/how-do-i-disable-automatic-closing-of-without-disabling-it-for-other-brackets).

After I installed [rust.vim](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim), when I type `<`, neovim automatically inserts closing angular bracket `>`. This might be useful for some people, but I find it annoying and I want to disable it.

P.S. I considered posting this question on the vi and vim stack exchange, but there was no tag for rust, so I decided to post here.

Comment: I doubt installing rust.vim did that. Do you have some "autopairs" or "delimitmate" or some similar plugin?

Comment: Yes, I do have delimitmate. Please note that my neovim does NOT automatically insert closing angular bracket without rust.vim. It inserts closing bracket only after installing rust.vim.

Comment: Possibly related  to: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/rust.vim#L63-L79

Comment: I removed all the code you pointed out, but it still gives me closing bracket.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I deleted delimitmate and tried again with rust.vim. It didn't give me closing bracket like I imagined. So the problem is the compatibility of delimitmate and rust.vim.

Comment: Well yeah, rust.vim entirely depends on delimitmate/autopairs for that.

Answer (score 3):

All I had to do was override whatever rust.vim did to cause this. So, I put `au FileType rust let b:delimitMate_matchpairs = "(:),[:],{:}"` at the bottom of `init.vim` file and now all the rust files only allow `()`, `[]`, `{}` to automatically insert closing brackets, and not `<>`. Additionally, I didn't like automatic closing for `''` because lifetime syntax in rust only uses one `'`, so I put `au FileType rust let b:delimitMate_quotes = "\""` and now it only allows automatic closing for `""`, and not `''`. As a reference, I used [this](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/issues/119).